# Iterate through nested objects to form a string

Tags: javascript, loops, nested

I have the following array, containing multiple nested objects (the nesting level could be infinite) :

```
var logicRules = [
    {
        'operator' : null,
        'conditionString' : 'x == y'
    },
    {
        'operator' : 'and',
        'conditionString' : 'x > y'
    },
    {
        'operator' : 'or',
        'rules' : [
            {
                'operator' : null,
                'conditionString' : 'x <= y'
            },
            {
                'operator' : 'and',
                'conditionString' : 'x > y'
            },
            {
                'operator' : 'and',
                'rules' : [
                    {
                        'operator' : null,
                        'conditionString' : 'x < y'
                    },
                    {
                        'operator' : 'or',
                        'conditionString' : 'x != y'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'operator' : 'and',
                'conditionString' : 'x == y'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'operator' : 'and',
        'conditionString' : 'x >= y'
    }
];
```

If I perform `processCondition(logicRules)` (see function below), the goal is to end up with a string like this :

```
if(x == y && x > y || (x <= y && x > y && (x < y || x != y)) && x >= y){ doSomething(); }
```

*I will later eval() this string. And yes many front-end and back-end precautions are taken to make sure the eval() is safe to execute.*

Below is my latest effort to achieve my goal. And yes I'm aware it is completely off in some parts. I just can't figure out how to solve it and it's driving me nuts.

```
function processCondition(rules){

    var fullConditionString = "if(";
    _processConditionsRecursive(rules);

    function _processConditionsRecursive(logicRules, isGrouped){
      var groupedConditionString = (typeof isGrouped != "undefined" && isGrouped) ? "(" : "";
      for (var key in logicRules) {
        if (logicRules.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

          if(typeof logicRules[key].rules != "undefined" && logicRules[key].rules.length){
             groupedConditionString += '(' + _processLogicRulesRecursive(logicRules[key].rules, true) + ')';
          }else{
            groupedConditionString += " " + logicRules[key].conditionString + " ";
          }

        }
      }

      groupedConditionString += (typeof isGrouped != "undefined" && isGrouped) ? ")" : "";

      fullConditionString += groupedConditionString;

      return groupedConditionString;

    }

    fullConditionString += '){ doSomething(); }';

    return fullConditionString;

}
```

(!) I can do the operator separation myself no problem. Right now I'm mostly just worried about grouping conditions in brackets.

Thank you so very much!

Comment: This is a quite weird AST. Where does it come from? Also, with a proper AST you don't need to generate code and eval it, you can evaluate straight from the AST.

Comment: @georg Mind if I ask you why it is weird? I initially designed it in a way that it would properly and easily render my condition creation tool in a different page of my system. At the time it felt like it wouldn't give me any problems once I would have to translate that same AST into a condition string.

Comment: Normally, a node for a binary op would look like this `{operator, left, right}`, in your example it would be `{and, {==, x, y}, {or, etc}`. This way it would be much easier to  generate code or to evaluate directly.

Comment: e.g. http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=x%20%3D%3D%20y%20%26%26%20x%20%3E%20y%20%7C%7C%20(x%20%3C%3D%20y%20%26%26%20x%20%3E%20y%20%26%26%20(x%20%3C%20y%20%7C%7C%20x%20!%3D%20y))%20%26%26%20x%20%3E%3D%20y

Comment: @georg Ah. I see what you mean and I absolutely agree. Hopefully I don't have to change the structure at this point, but I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using recursive function with `reduce` method.

```js
var rules = [{"operator":null,"conditionString":"x == y"},{"operator":"and","conditionString":"x > y"},{"operator":"or","rules":[{"operator":null,"conditionString":"x <= y"},{"operator":"and","conditionString":"x > y"},{"operator":"and","rules":[{"operator":null,"conditionString":"x < y"},{"operator":"or","conditionString":"x != y"}]},{"operator":"and","conditionString":"x == y"}]},{"operator":"and","conditionString":"x >= y"}]

function process(rules) {
  return rules.reduce((r, e, i) => {
    let nested = ''
    let op = '';
    let cond = '';

    if (e.rules) {
      nested = process(e.rules);
    }

    if (e.conditionString) {
      cond = e.conditionString
    }
  
    if(i === 0) op = '';
    else if (e.operator === 'and') op = '&&';
    else if (e.operator === 'or') op = '||';

    r += (op ? ` ${op} ` : '') + cond + (nested ? `(${nested})` : '')

    return r;
  }, '')
}

const result = process(rules);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hey Nenad! Thanks a million for your help, I truly appreciate it. I tested your code and it works wonderfully! One thing unfortunately; I made small changes for simplicity's sake in my code above and I didn't think it would influence people's answers. The only difference in my actual code, every rule's operator has an "and" or "or". There are no "null" operators. In my head, I was just going to ignore the operator if my loop's index was 0, but in your example, there is no index. I was wondering if you had any idea on how to adapt to this situation? Thank you so much!

Comment: If I understood correctly, this should work https://jsfiddle.net/zwh76d2e/

Comment: Nenad; I can't thank you enough. Seriously. I know StackOverflow discourages "thanks" comments, but I couldn't help still express it. I've learned a lot from your code already upon looking up the "reduce" method. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Justin01  I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the arrays by looking to the first item and omit any operator and by checking if `rules` exists, then take the nested elements or the condition.

```js
function combine(r, { operator, conditionString, rules }, i) {
    var ops = { and: '&&', or: '||' };
    return r + (i ? ` ${ops[operator]} ` : '') + (rules
        ? `(${rules.reduce(combine, '')})`
        : conditionString
    );
}

var logicRules = [{ operator: null, conditionString: "x == y" }, { operator: "and", conditionString: "x > y" }, { operator: "or", rules: [{ operator: null, conditionString: "x <= y" }, { operator: "and", conditionString: "x > y" }, { operator: "and", rules: [{ operator: null, conditionString: "x < y" }, { operator: "or", conditionString: "x != y" }] }, { operator: "and", conditionString: "x == y" }] }, { operator: "and", conditionString: "x >= y" }],
    result = logicRules.reduce(combine, '');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey Nina, thanks a ton for your help and contribution. I decided to go with Nenad's answer. Thank you very much once again. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Hey Justin, 
I have written a recursive method to resolve your issues. Please compare your 
code with mine. I hope this resolves your issue.

/* Recursive generator function */
function logicGenerator(logicRules, str) {

/* Checking whether rules are there */
if (logicRules.length) {
   /* Looping through each rule */  
   for (const rule of logicRules) {

   switch (rule.operator) {
    case null: 
      str += ` (`;
      break;
    case "and":
      str += ` &&`;
      break;
    case "or":
      str += `||`;
      break;
  }
  /* Adding the expression to the string */
  if (rule.conditionString) str += ` ${rule.conditionString} `;

  /* If there are rules available then calling the method recursively and 
     passing the string generated so far */
  if (rule.rules && rule.rules.length)
    str = ` ${logicGenerator(rule.rules, str)}`;
 }
}
    // Adding the close parenthesis 
    str += `)`;
    return str; 
}

/* Wrapper function */
function generateLogicString(logicRules) {
  return logicGenerator(logicRules, ""); 
}


Runner method

const result = eval(generateLogicString(logicRules))

-----------------------------
I have tested the above code with below long input and it is working fine

var logicRules = [
{
operator: null,
rules: [
  {
    operator: null,
    conditionString: "x <= y"
  },
  {
    operator: "and",
    conditionString: "x > y"
  },
  {
    operator: "and",
    rules: [
      {
        operator: null,
        conditionString: "x < y"
      },
      {
        operator: "or",
        conditionString: "x != y"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    operator: "and",
    conditionString: "x == y"
  }
 ]
 },
 {
operator: "and",
conditionString: "x > y"
},
{
operator: "or",
rules: [
  {
    operator: null,
    conditionString: "x <= y"
  },
  {
    operator: "and",
    conditionString: "x > y"
  },
  {
    operator: "and",
    rules: [
      {
        operator: null,
        conditionString: "x < y"
      },
      {
        operator: "or",
        rules: [
          {
            operator: null,
            conditionString: "x <= y"
          },
          {
            operator: "and",
            conditionString: "x > y"
          },
          {
            operator: "and",
            rules: [
              {
                operator: null,
                conditionString: "x < y"
              },
              {
                operator: "or",
                rules: [
                  {
                    operator: null,
                    conditionString: "x <= y"
                  },
                  {
                    operator: "and",
                    conditionString: "x > y"
                  },
                  {
                    operator: "and",
                    rules: [
                      {
                        operator: null,
                        rules: [
                          {
                            operator: null,
                            conditionString: "x <= y"
                          },
                          {
                            operator: "and",
                            rules: [
                              {
                                operator: null,
                                conditionString: "x <= y"
                              },
                              {
                                operator: "and",
                                conditionString: "x > y"
                              },
                              {
                                operator: "and",
                                rules: [
                                  {
                                    operator: null,
                                    conditionString: "x < y"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    operator: "or",
                                    conditionString: "x != y"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                operator: "and",
                                conditionString: "x == y"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            operator: "and",
                            rules: [
                              {
                                operator: null,
                                conditionString: "x < y"
                              },
                              {
                                operator: "or",
                                conditionString: "x != y"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            operator: "and",
                            conditionString: "x == y"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        operator: "or",
                        conditionString: "x != y"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    operator: "and",
                    conditionString: "x == y"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            operator: "and",
            conditionString: "x == y"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    operator: "and",
    conditionString: "x == y"
  }
 ]
},
{
 operator: "and",
 conditionString: "x >= y"
 } 
];
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey Arvind, thanks a ton. Unfortunately, I had already marked the question as "Answered" by the time you replied. Nenad provided me with a working solution. Still, I very much wanted to thank you for your time and efforts. I have read through your code and it looks to me like it would have worked just as well. Thanks a ton!